# div containers inside w3-tab (Navigation as Page Tabulators) W3 CSS

Tags: html, css

I am new to html and css in particular. I found the W3.CSS template and trying to modify it. I am trying to make a navigation toolbar as in this example:
http://www.w3schools.com/w3css/tryit.asp?filename=tryw3css_nav_topnav_tab

but I want to place additional "containers" inside each of the 3 main ones. However, the additional `<div>` are never shown. Here is an example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>W3.CSS</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3.css">
<body>

<div class="w3-topnav w3-red">
  <a href="#link1">London</a>
  <a href="#link2">Paris</a>
  <a href="#link3">Tokyo</a>
</div>

<div class="w3-tab">
<div id="link1" class="w3-container">
  <h2>London</h2>
  <p>London is the capital city of England.</p>
  <p>It is the most populous city in the United Kingdom,
  with a metropolitan area of over 13 million inhabitants.</p>  

<div class="w3-row">
<div class="w3-container w3-half">
    <h2>w3-half</h2> 
    <p>This is a paragraph</p>
  </div>
  <div class="w3-container w3-half">
    <h2>w3-half</h2> 
    <p>This is a paragraph</p>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="link2" class="w3-container">
  <h2>Paris</h2>
  <p>Paris is the capital of France.</p> 
  <p>The Paris area is one of the largest population centers in Europe,
  with more than 12 million inhabitants.</p>
</div>
<div id="link3" class="w3-container">
<h2>Tokyo</h2>
  <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
  <p>It is the center of the Greater Tokyo Area,
  and the most populous metropolitan area in the world.</p>
</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: "W3.CSS" … I really wish W3Schools would stop publishing stuff with names that people could easily mistake for being from the W3 Consortium.

Comment: … and having had a poke at it, I'd honestly suggest using something else. Something with an actual license, a version control repository, an archive of old versions, and with a community behind it.

Comment: @Quentin any suggestions?

Comment: Twitter Bootstrap is the market leader.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.w3-tab div` display is hidden and you need to change it. Also, the HTML structure is not correct. Use the following:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>W3.CSS</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3.css">
    <style>
        .w3-row, .w3-half {
            display:block !important;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <div class="w3-topnav w3-red">
        <a href="#link1">London</a>
        <a href="#link2">Paris</a>
        <a href="#link3">Tokyo</a>
    </div>

    <div class="w3-tab">
        <div id="link1" class="w3-container">
            <h2>London</h2>
            <p>London is the capital city of England.</p>
            <p>It is the most populous city in the United Kingdom, with a metropolitan area of over 13 million inhabitants.</p>

            <div class="w3-row">
                <div class="w3-container w3-half">
                    <h2>w3-half</h2>
                    <p>This is a paragraph</p>
                </div>
                <div class="w3-container w3-half">
                    <h2>w3-half</h2>
                    <p>This is a paragraph</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="link2" class="w3-container">
            <h2>Paris</h2>
            <p>Paris is the capital of France.</p>
            <p>The Paris area is one of the largest population centers in Europe, with more than 12 million inhabitants.</p>
        </div>
        <div id="link3" class="w3-container">
            <h2>Tokyo</h2>
            <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
            <p>It is the center of the Greater Tokyo Area, and the most populous metropolitan area in the world.</p>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The previous version only showed one of 3 sections at a time. Is there a way to keep this feature?

Comment: @user1830663 What do you mean one of 3 sections?

Comment: In the original example, clicking "London" only shows the <div id="link1" class="w3-container">. I would like to keep the same feature but with additional <div> inside the main ones with the "id". So when clicking on London I dont want to see Paris and Tokyo.

Comment: Thanks! that works. So essentially I put any type of container I use inside the main <div>s to the <style> section in the header?

Comment: @user1830663 you do not need to. Just use the same class for all the new divs you create. Follow the same HTML code and it should work for you.